# Ceiling Framing on Stand alone room

Tags: framing

Pretty handy man and have built plenty of walls in preexisting structures but I’m wanting to build a man-cave/poker room inside of my shop.
The shop is 16' tall and room will have standard 8' walls. The dimensions of the room I’m wanting to build are roughly 28'x15'.
I have all of the wall framing and such figured out but not exactly sure how to do the ceiling.
Since it's inside of my shop I obviously won't be putting a roof or anything like that on it, just need to have something to hang Sheetrock from and won’t sag over time or from lights/fans.
I will add that I would like to end up using the space above it to store Christmas lights and such but nothing with a whole lot of weight.

Comment: So you would like to have ceiling joists spanning the 15' room with no support in the middle?  Sounds reasonable.

Comment: Yeah that’s why I was asking because of saggage. There will be other walls for bathroom/storage but also be parts that are that wide without. Guessing you suggest support beams? Also what is the longest span you could run without support?

Comment: Oh, no I wasn't being sarcastic at all.  A 16' span should be fine with 2x8s.  Take a look at [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/82822/43874).  Framing is not my specialty, but someone else might have better references or suggestions.

Comment: I'd be wary of the desire to store heavier things - or rather, I'd plan for it. I'd also compare the prices of TJIs and plain lumber in your local market before making a final decision.

Comment: It's equally important that your ceiling/roof system has sufficient strength to keep the walls from falling inwards or outwards. That's more an issue for how the joists are attached to the wall headers, I think.

Comment: Sorry JPH guess I’m used to always dealing with sarcasm on the internet. Appreciate all yals feedback. Never heard of those joists before something definitely worth looking into. And I agree about planning for heavier stuff but Christmas decor will really be only thing we have 80X40 shop so plenty of storage. Also if I went with 2x8 or 2x10 would yal suggest offsetting spacers between them or not.